# keeping right-to-left direction in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, right-to-left

I use ctrl+alt+R to change the direction into right-to-left, but I want to keep it as my default direction so when I close it and open it again, I have the same direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add one attribute to language xml file

i.e. if you want to change language czech to RTL, then you must edit file czech.xml in c:\Program Files\Notepad++\localization\ directory (it is the location, where the notepad++ was installed).

Then you must find tag Native-Langue and add attritube RTL="yes" to it.

i.e. before change:

```
 <Native-Langue name = "Čeština" filename="czech.xml" version="6.6.8">
```

after change:

```
 <Native-Langue name = "Čeština" RTL="yes" filename="czech.xml" version="6.6.8">
```

then only restart Notepad++.

Here is [link](http://notepad.cwaniak.info/documentation/notepad-user-manual/display/right-left-rtl.html) to the official manual with brief description

Comment: there is only English.xml in that directory. How can I create this file for Farsi language?

Comment: OK. I found it. +1